# Gatling: transform findAll to sorted list

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm new to scala and Gatling. I'm trying to transform the result of findAll into a sorted list and then return a String representation of the sorted list. I can't seem to do this with the following code:

```
http(requestTitle)
  .post(serverUrl)
  .body(ElFileBody(sendMessageFile))
  .header("correlation-id", correlationId)
  .check(status.is(200),
    jsonPath("$.data.sendMessage.targetedRecipients").findAll.transform(recipients => {
      println("recipients class: " + recipients.getClass)
      var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer(recipients: _*)
      var sortedRecipients = mutable.sortWith(_ < _)
      println("users sorted "+ usersSorted)
      usersSorted.mkString(",")
  }).is(expectedMessageRecipients))
```

Recipients is of type scala.collection.immutable.Vector.
I thought I would be able to convert the immutable collection into a mutable collection using scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is no reason for you to use mutable collection here if all you want is to sort the result.

Comment: Calling recipients.sortWith(_ < _) doesn't sort the collection of Strings. My thinking was because it's immutable.

Comment: `Vector("5","4","3","2","1").sortWith(_ < _).mkString(", ") == "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"` - vector is immutable so it *doesn't mutate code in place* BUT it *returns updated copy* - just store the result in a variable because you use it as an expression and not as a statement.

Comment: I understand that it returns an updated copy, I tried to store the result of sortWith in a different variable as you suggested but it's not working for me.

Comment: Are you sure this is an immutable vector?

Comment: The result of println("recipients class: " + recipients.getClass) is "recipients class: class scala.collection.immutable.Vector"

Comment: can you post your response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem is immutability, it's JSON parsing vs Gatling's .find and .findAll methods.

I'm going to make a guess that your response looks something like...

```
{"data":{"sendMessage":{"targetedRecipients":[1,4,2,3]}}}
```

in which case Gatling's .findAll method will return a vector (it always does if it finds something), but it will only have one element which will be "[1,4,2,3]" - ie: a string representing json data, so sorting the collection of a single element naturally achieves nothing. To get .findAll to behave like you seem to be expecting, you would need a response something like...

```
{"data":
 {"sendMessage":
  {"targetedRecipients":
    [{"recipientId":1},
     {"recipientId":4},
     {"recipientId":2},
     {"recipientId":3}]
 }}}
```

which you could use `.jsonPath("$..recipientId").findAll`to turn into a Vector[String] of the Ids.

So assuming you are indeed just getting a single string representation of an array of values, you could use a straight transform to generate an array and sort (as you tried in your example)

Here's a working version

```
val data = """{"data":{"sendMessage":{"targetedRecipients":[1,4,2,3]}}}"""

def sortedArray : ScenarioBuilder = scenario("sorting an array")
.exec(http("test call")
.post("http://httpbin.org/anything")
.body(StringBody(data)).asJson
.check(
  status.is(200),
  jsonPath("$.json.data.sendMessage.targetedRecipients")
    .find
    .transform(_
      .drop(1)
      .dropRight(1)
      .split(",")
      .toVector
      .sortWith(_<_)
    )
    .saveAs("received")
))
.exec(session => {
  println(s"received: ${session("received").as[Vector[String]]}")
  session
})
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that the findAll returned a vector of length 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use mutable collection if all you want is to sort the result:

```
Vector(5,4,3,2,1).sortWith(_ < _).mkString(", ") // "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

To use `ListBuffer` you have to copy all elements into newly allocated object, so it isn't even more optimal in any way. Same with `var`s - you can use `val`s as you don't update the reference

```
println(s"recipients class: ${recipients.getClass}")
val result = recipients.sortWith(_ < _).mkString(", ")
println(s"users sorted $result")
result
```